# Rails3 ActionView Template Handlers doesn't work on Production Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, production-environment, actionview

I am using Rails 3.2.3 / Ruby 1.9.3p125 / jbuilder (0.4.0)

In my `view/mycontroller` folder i got a `show.json.jbuilder` file.
when I test everything on my local machine with `rails s -e production` everything works fine.
The JSON gets rendered as espected.

But when I deploy to Ubuntu LTS (nginx/unicorn) I get the following Error Message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template mycontroller/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:de, :en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/deployer/apps/myapp/releases/#############/app/views"
):
```

When I check on my server if the jbuilder gem is installed with `bundle show jbuilder` everything seems right.

weird is that the Error message does't show `:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :jbuilder]`
The jbuilder handler is obviously missing. But how do I solve the problem?

**Edit:** The Problem is not based on Jbuilder. I tried rabl and the same problem appears.

Does any one has a hint, how to debug this?

**Here some more Information:**

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'simple_form'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.2'
end

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

# for performance monitoring
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

# use asset pipline and flash
gem 'swf_fu', '~> 2.0'

gem 'geocoder'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
gem 'jbuilder'
```

Controller

```
  def show

  end
```

show.json.jbuilder - file

```
 json.(@map, :id)
```

Comment: What does your gem file look like ?

Comment: cant you share some source code? It's pretty hard to tell anything from just what you said...

Comment: What bundler version do you have (on your production machine, but if that's different to your local machine, that's good to know too)

Comment: I got Bundler version 1.1.3 on both production & development

Comment: just general assumptions, try two terminal commands:

$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle update
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Comment: Are your actual gem versions the same between the dev environment & production? Don't know where else to start, but Bundler causes me lots of problems over time if I don't specify all gem versions exactly.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your jbuilder seems to be skipped.

Is jbuilder in your Gemfile.lock file?

```
cat Gemfile.lock | grep jbuilder
```

If it's missing:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle update jbuilder
```

Is jbuilder loadable?

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
> require 'jbuilder'
=> false  # this is false if jbuilder is pre-loaded
```

Can you build in the console?

```
> Jbuilder.encode{|j| j.foo :bar }
=> "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

Can you build in your controller action?

```
def the_method_you_are_testing
   raise Jbuilder.encode{|j| j.foo :bar }
end
```

Do you see the same error with a different server setup, such as Apache & Passenger instead of Nginx & Unicorn, or simply rails server?

```
rails server -e production
```

Do you get the same results if you change your server app from production to development?

```
rails server -e development
```

For RABL, can you try putting the RABL gem *last* in your Gemfile?

```
gem 'rails'
#...
gem 'rabl'
```

Try registering immediately after requiring builder?

```
require 'tilt'
require 'rabl'
# ...
require 'builder'
Rabl.register!
```

Do you get the same results with RABL master?

```
gem 'rabl', :git => "git://github.com/nesquena/rabl.git"
```

Comment: Everything works fine on my local mashine. It is also in the gemfile.log. Thanks for you Debugging tip!

Comment: Do these same debugging tips all work on your production server?

Comment: Debugging tips all work fine for me, I also have the same problem.There seems to be something 'blocking' these template engines

Comment: @jamesw if your project is on github or open source, I'm happy to take a look and see if I can help

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson - Thank's for the offer. I'm pretty sure this is a server configuration issue (nginx/unicorn) rather than a coding issue. I'm using as_json for now. Due to the sensitivity of app I'm unable to let you in to my private repository or my server. I have had some correspondence with Nathan (owner of Rabl gem), but nothing concrete has come out of that yet. I'll post back here if I ever find the solution. I'd be interested to know if you have the time to set up a test if it is an issue with nginx/unicorn - something I should try myself given a little spare time.

Comment: @jamesw Added more debugging tips for you... see if any help.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I have the same problem here, using rabl. Seems that the problems is with the nginx+unicorn combo...

Comment: My fix happened to be in the controller. I had to change: "format.json { render json: @records }" to "format.json" and the index.json.jbuilder file I had in place started getting used.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the load order when rails boots in production. It's needs to be fixed in jbuilder, but here is a workaround:

Gemfile:

```
gem :jbuilder, :require=>false
```

config/initializers/jbuilder.rb:

```
require 'jbuilder'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using [grape-jbuilder](https://github.com/milkcocoa/grape-jbuilder) then their suggestion to add to configu.ru may be causing your problem.

If you are using Rails and grape-jbuilder, then make sure you first require the Rails environment prior to including grape-jbuilder.

## config.ru

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'grape/jbuilder'

use Rack::Config do |env|
  env['api.tilt.root'] = 'app/views/api'
end

run Rails.application
```