# Rails 3.2.2 - Possible to add custom node to as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

As it's not currently possible for me to use a json templating engine (jbuilder or rabl) as per [Rails3 ActionView Template Handlers doesn't work on Production Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520269/rails3-actionview-template-handlers-doesnt-work-on-production-server) I'm wondering how to best change this controller action to include a custom node with as_json (or something else)

```
class Mobile::AndroidUsersController < SecureMobileUserController
  skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => :create
  respond_to :json  

  # POST /mobile_users
  # POST /mobile_users.xml
  def create
    @mobile_user = AndroidUser.find_by_auth(params[:mobile_user][:auth])
    unless @mobile_user
      @mobile_user = AndroidUser.new(params[:mobile_user])
    else
      @mobile_user.attributes = params[:mobile_user]
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mobile_user.save
        format.json #Add a custom token node here
      else
:unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @mobile_user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
:unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I just need to add a custom node called token that has a value that I get from calling a method on the MobileUser class

```
:token => MobileUser.next_token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the call to as_json like this:

```
format.json {render :json => @mobile_user.as_json(:methods => [:next_token])}
```